# Object and Function are quite confusing

Tags: javascript

```
Object instanceof Object
true
Object instanceof Function
true
Function instanceof Object
true
Function instanceof Function
true
```

so if Function is an Object and the Object is a Function how come

`Function === Object` and `Function == Object` are false?

I do understand that checking the instance of an object is not the same as comparison. So the question here is the fuzziness in the case where if two objects (which are actually types) are instances of each other, shouldn't the types be the same?

Note: Object is not an instance of a Number or an Array just an instance of Function.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From [JavaScript Prototypal Inheritance](http://www.3site.eu/doc/#Object):

> Quite everything, in JavaScript, inherits from Object. We could say
>   that Object is the super class, or better, the super constructor, of
>   every variable and that everything is an instanceof Object. The Object
>   constructor is a Function, but a Function is an instanceof Object.
>   This means that these assertions are always true:
>
> `(Object instanceof Function) === (Function instanceof Object)`
>
> Above example is true because Object is a constructor, and a constructor in JavaScript is always a Function. At the same
>   time, every Function has its own prototype, and a prototype always
>   starts its inheritance from Object.prototype. The Function
>   constructor, is a Function itself, and the function prototype is a
>   function(){};
>
> `(Function.prototype instanceof Object) === (function(){} instanceof Object)`

Comment: +1 for saying the same thing I said but in a much more concise and easy-to-understand way. xD

Comment: `Quite everything, in JavaScript, inherits from Object` and then ES5 came: `var notObject = Object.create(null); notObject instanceof Object; //false`

Comment: That is the most confusing explanation I have ever seen.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 True. And of course, even before ES5 the assertion was wrong. Clearly, every prototype chain is finite, thus `Object.prototype instanceof Object === false`

Answer (score 5):

Everything is an `Object` in JavaScript because JavaScript is an object-oriented language. `Function` is an instance of `Object` because everything is an instance of `Object`. Simple enough. However, objects that initialize other objects (constructors) are also `Function`s in JavaScript, so it would make sense for `Object` to also be a `Function`.

Think about this:

```
var obj = new Object();
```

`Object` in this case is used as a `Function`, is it not? So while, in theory, `Object` should be the lowest-level object in the language, JavaScript cannot function without `Function`s (pun!), so you need both to be at the same level. `Object` needs to be an instance of `Function` because it's a constructor and it needs to create more instances of itself.

```
function FooBar() {}
```

The `FooBar` class above is an instance of both `Object` and `Function`, because it's both. The same logic applies to the built-in `Object` and `Function` objects; they're instances of both.

Phew, confusing. Did that make any sense?

Comment: Makes sense to me, but as you can probably see I had just as much trouble (unsuccessfully) trying to explain the same thing :-P

Comment: Haha yeah, it's not easy to explain!

Comment: It certainly makes sense given that it is Javascript, in no other language that I know of do you instantiate a function (of type Function), you only invoke it. Appreciate your effort in trying to answer the right question.

Comment: there are many Functional Programming languages that can have functions that generate functions LISP, LOGO, ... even BASIC! (the technique involves creating a string and embedding it in the BASIC program as a line - the embedded string would define a function)

Answer (score 4):

I think this is more due to the unique way in which objects are defined. You don't define a type in javascript, you define a constructor. But you also do not define the constructor as a constructor, it's simply a function.

You can then refer to the types by the name of their constructor....which is just a function.

```
function Tiger(){ //function, or object?
}

function Apple(){ //function, or object?
}
```

Both *could* be objects, or perhaps just functions. Only the way you use them will determine that. So it *kind of* makes sense that at a low level, objects are functions and functions are objects, but there is still a difference, right?

Comment: Regarding your comment method or object, it is definitely not a method unless it is called with some scope.

Comment: Ah, yes, is this a terminology clash here - would "//FUNCTION, or Object?" be a better comment?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as classes in Javascript. The `instanceof` operator is called on functions.

`Object` is a constructor function for "Object objects" (yes, this is the official term), and `Function` is the constructor function for "Function objects".

So, when you call `Function instanceof Object`, it returns `true` because `Function` is a function, and thus an object, etc. This does not mean that the types are the same, because Object and Function have different prototypes:

```
Object.prototype
   ^
   | inherits from
   |                instance
Function.prototype  <-------  Object, Function
```

Comment: Nice copy and pasting from your last answer.

Comment: ...since the question was closed as a duplicate

Comment: I deleted the other answer, to avoid duplicate content :)

Comment: But what is not shown in diagram is Object.prototype.constructor === Object but Object instance of Function.prototype. This whole thing has no logic no matter how any one tries to explain.

Answer (score 0):

```
 javascript:alert([ window.navigator.userAgent, Object ].join("\n\n") )
```

displays

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100423 
    Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.3

function Object() {
    [native code]
}
```

reference: [Is every JavaScript Object a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018023/is-every-javascript-object-a-function)

Comment: `javascript:alert(Function)` displays `function Function() {
    [native code]
}`

Answer (score 0):

*Suppose*:

**<---- : links to (via `.__proto__`)**

**<-- : has inherited property of (via `.`)**

*Then*:

**Function.prototype <---- {Object, Function}**

**Object <---- Function.prototype**

**Object.prototype <-- Object**

```
console.log(Object.prototype.constructor === Object); // true!
```

`Object.prototype` does **not** link to anything; it doesn't have `__proto__` property.

Answer (score -2):

instanceof operator indicates if the first argument is of the given type. That is saying

```
 A instanceof B
```

returns true if A is an instance of the type B.

The == and === operators are comparison operators on the other hand. They compare values for equality.

For instance, you can say jack instanceof Boy is true but would you say that jack == boy? No.

Comment: The OP's question is more about how `Object` and `Function` can be instances of each other and not be the same thing.