# In JavaScript: If Object is a function then how can it be if a function is an instance of an object

Tags: javascript, function, object

In other words what was first? An egg or a hen? I can't understand how JavaScript could be implemented since I read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function#Properties_and_Methods_of_Function .

As you see in console:

```
>Object instanceof Function
true
>new Function() instanceof Object
true
```

Seems like a fatal loop.

And why all of these:

```
typeof new Object()
typeof new Array()
typeof new Date()
typeof new RegExp()
typeof new Number()
typeof new Boolean()
typeof new String()
```

return "object", but this:

```
typeof new Function()
```

returns "function"

Seems like what... Is object derived from function?
I don't think so because:

```
>new Function() instanceof Object
true
>new Object() instanceof Function
false
```

So not...

Comment: `Object` *is* a function which is also an object, and `new` creates an object, which can be a function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why in JavaScript both "Object instanceof Function" and "Function instanceof Object" return true?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622695/why-in-javascript-both-object-instanceof-function-and-function-instanceof-obj) and [Object and Function are quite confusing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003183/object-and-function-are-quite-confusing)

Comment: `object` is a type; `Object` is a function and an object (all functions are objects); `Object` is a class that can construct objects of type `object` that are instances of the `Object` class. All other classes inherit from the base class `Object`. So instances of `new Function()` are functions, which are objects that are instances of the `Function` class whose base class is `Object`. So a function (or an object with the type `function`) is both a `Function` and an `Object`. Clear as mud, right?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are getting types, functions and objects confused.

**Short answer:**

In Javascript functions are objects. Objects are not functions, but functions exist that create and/or return objects.

**Detailed answer with examples:**

You are correct that functions are objects. `Object` is a function and so is `Function` as shown in the console output below.

But when you say that `Object` is a function, you are actually talking about the `Object()` function, and not the type `object`.

```
// Object is a function
> Object
function Object() { [native code] }

// Function is a function
> Function
function Function() { [native code] }

// The type of Object is function
> typeof(Object)
"function"

// The type of the result of invoking the Object() function (AKA constructor, since using "new" keyword) is a new object
> typeof(new Object())
"object"

> new Object() instanceof Object
true
> new Function() instanceof Function
true
// note the difference
> new Object() instanceof Function
false
> new Function() instanceof Object
true
```

In your example in some cases you are actually invoking the function and looking at the result of the function, and not the function itself. For example, `typeof(String) === "function"` but `typeof(new String()) === "object"` (a "String" object in this case).

When you invoked these functions with the `new` keyword you got a new object whose class is the name of the function you invoked. The reason that `new Function() instanceof Object === true` is that `Object` is the base class for any object constructed in this way. `Object` is the name of the base class, and the type of the instance is `"object"` (that is, the object created from the class, like cookies from a cookie cutter).